# How to change response each time a user asks something again?

Tags: python, chatbot

**I want the bot to respond differently to same question. Please Help me I know i am silly but i'm learning to code.**

```
def chatbot(n):
 if n=="ARE U REAL?" or n=="are u real?" or n=="are you real" or n=="are you real" or n=="Are you real?" or n=="are u real":
    print("BOT: YES, As Real as You.") #or print("BOT:Yes") #or print("BOT:OFCOURSE")#if asked again should change its reply

#WHATS YOUR NAME

 elif n=="What's your name?" or n=='what is your name?' or n=='whats your name?' or n=='whats your name' or n=='what is your name':  
    print("BOT: My software says that My name is ChatBot \U0001F604 ")
 else:
    print("BOT: Sorry I can't respond to that,Try asking another question")
    prompt=input('Or Do you want to search again on Google? Y=Yes and N=No:').lower()
    if prompt=='y' or prompt=='yes':
        query = input("Search on Google:")
        webbrowser.open("https://google.com/search?q=%s" % query)
    else:
        print("BOT: Ok :)")


    print("BOT: HEY IM CHATBOT MAY I KNOW YOUR NAME?")
    a=input('YOU:')
    print("BOT: Hi",a.upper())

    while True:
        print("BOT: ASK ME SOMETHING",a.upper(), "\U0001F642 OR PRESS q TO EXIT!")
        n=input("YOU:").lower()
        if n != 'q':
           chatbot(n)
    else:
       print("BOT: BYE :)")
       break
```

Explanation of the changes would help me a lot thanks.

Comment: make a global list outside the function scope and append each request to that list. in the function then check whether the request already is in that list

Comment: i don't know how to make one can you help me or could u edit this and give me one example

Comment: insert `history = []` before the function.in the function do `global history` then check `if n in history:` and do the thing you want. Also before asking for help why don't you learn the language yourself or google a bit. It really doesn't take that much effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will not be editing your code but rather give you a minimal example because this how we learn after all. So, from my point of view, you could definitely be using the `random` built-in library and something like this instead of looping on a set of pre-defined answers in one never-changing order:

```
# import library to choose a random item in a list
from random import choice

# set the list of possible answers
answers = ["Yes, I'm real!", "I am real indeed.", "Would you believe me if I said yes?"]

# choose a random answer from the list of possible answers
answer = choice(answers)

print(answer)

# > "I am real indeed."
```

Answer (score 0):

THANKS SEVERUS

```
from random import choice
 def chatbot(n):
 if n=="ARE U REAL?" or n=="are u real?" or n=="are you real" or n=="are you real" or 
 n=="Are you real?" or n=="are u real":
     answers = ["Yes, I'm real!", "I am real indeed.", "Would you believe me if I 
 said yes?"]
     answer = choice(answers)
     print(answer)

 elif n=="What's your name?" or n=='what is your name?' or n=='whats your name?' or n=='whats your name' or n=='what is your name':  
       answers = ["chatbot!", "I am real chabot.", "Would you believe me if I said siri?"]
       answer = choice(answers)
       print(answer)
 else:
    print("BOT: Sorry I can't respond to that,Try asking another question")
    prompt=input('Or Do you want to search again on Google? Y=Yes and N=No:').lower()
    if prompt=='y' or prompt=='yes':
        query = input("Search on Google:")
        webbrowser.open("https://google.com/search?q=%s" % query)
    else:
        print("BOT: Ok :)")


   print("BOT: HEY IM CHATBOT MAY I KNOW YOUR NAME?")
   a=input('YOU:')
   print("BOT: Hi",a.upper())

   while True:
   print("BOT: ASK ME SOMETHING",a.upper(), "\U0001F642 OR PRESS q TO EXIT!")
   n=input("YOU:").lower()
   if n != 'q':
      chatbot(n)
   else:
      print("BOT: BYE :)")
      break
```

That's exactly what i needed.